# How to use sed command to edit nano's rcfile (interface element colors)

Tags: linux, sed, regular-expression

Here's a sample of my `nanorc` file:

```
(...)
## Detect word boundaries differently by treating punctuation
## characters as parts of words.
# set wordbounds

## The characters (besides alphanumeric ones) that should be considered
## as parts of words.  This option does not have a default value.  When
## set, it overrides option 'set wordbounds'.
# set wordchars "<_>."


## Paint the interface elements of nano.  These are examples;
## by default there are no colors, except for errorcolor.
# set titlecolor brightwhite,blue
# set statuscolor brightwhite,green
# set errorcolor brightwhite,red
# set selectedcolor brightwhite,magenta
# set numbercolor cyan
# set keycolor cyan
# set functioncolor green
## In root's .nanorc you might want to use:
# set titlecolor brightwhite,magenta
# set statuscolor brightwhite,magenta
# set errorcolor brightwhite,red
# set selectedcolor brightwhite,cyan
# set numbercolor magenta
# set keycolor brightmagenta
# set functioncolor magenta


## Setup of syntax coloring.
##
## Format:
##
## syntax "short description" ["filename regex" ...]
(...)
```

I need to change the `## Paint the interface elements of nano.` block to this:

```
## Paint the interface elements of nano.  These are examples;
## by default there are no colors, except for errorcolor.
set titlecolor brightwhite,blue
set statuscolor brightwhite,green
set errorcolor brightwhite,red
set selectedcolor brightwhite,magenta
set numbercolor cyan
set keycolor cyan
set functioncolor green
```

In other words, uncomment the first block of colors and delete the second block of colors (which is recommended for root's `.nanorc` only).

How can I achieve this with the sed command? If multiple sed commands (instead of a big one) makes it simple and easier to read, I'd prefer that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
sed "/## Paint the interface elements of nano./,/^$/ \
     {s/^# //; /## In root's .nanorc you might want to use:/,/^$/d}" infile
```

This will look for the lines between `## Paint the interface elements of nano.` and first empty line, then Uncomment those lines if starts with hash-space `#` , and delete everything else between the line start with `## In root's .nanorc you might want to use:` until a blank line in same block found at first, We used `{...}` to apply that *sed-script* only the block we need, and `sed` will print every thing else line if doesn't match with the condition which is `sed` default action.

Comment: Perfect. After testing, I added the `-i` flag for inplace editing :) Thank you very much.